# Slow response from Neo4j Embedded Server for several seconds when it starts

Tags: neo4j

I am running neo4j server in embedded mode. I am facing some performance related issue while server getting up for several seconds after that all is fine.

Where as properly shutting the server down even there is no log which says that database is returning from inconsistent state so It's all fine with shutdown and startup of neo4j server.

Even loaded reference node by getting a property out of it. Still it is slow for some seconds.

Comment: I needs to warm up its caches. So that is normal, also happens in embedded mode.

Comment: Hey Michaeal, Did not get your point ? please can you explain it better ? or Is it a normal behavior at startup i.e. supposed to happen. If this is the case then how to handle this on production environment server ?